# Parsing formatted time string (inverse of format-time-string)

Tags: time-date, parse-time

The `format-time-string` function takes a time argument like `'(21761 64499 350937 0)` and a format string like `"%y-%m-%d %a %H:%M"` and returns something like `"15-03-12 Thu 16:49"`.

What is the inverse function, which takes `"15-03-12 Thu 16:49"` and `"%y-%m-%d %a %H:%M"`, and returns `'(21761 64499 350937 0)`?

I am trying to parse times out of a website so as to convert them into org-mode timestamps, but I'm having trouble finding the right function in the emacs documentation.

**Edit** I'm promoting this from my comment to erikstoke's answer. `parse-time-string` and `org-parse-time-string` are insufficient because while they parse many standard time strings, they do not allow for specified formats. Both functions are rather incomprehensive. In particular, they lack [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) support.

Answer (score 5):

`parse-time-string` parses "standard" time strings, as does `org-parse-time-string`. The documentation claims the latter will be faster.  Neither gives a way to specify the format of the string.

There is also an undocumented function `parse-iso8601-time-string` that parses ISO8601 into something.  It isn't clear to me what the output is supposed to be.

Comment: Indeed, I checked those out. They even return "Invalid time specification" when fed ISO8601, which is why I'm still looking.

Comment: `(parse-time-string (current-time-string))` works here.

Comment: There is a function that claims to do this, but I don't see what the output is supposed to mean. I edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation but couldn't find anything working out of the box. But since `org-time-stamp` handles all kinds of formats, I figured the code was there. The function below will insert an org time stamp from a provided time string. I haven't tested it for all kinds of times, but for `"15-03-12 Thu 16:49"` it will give `"[2015-03-12 tor 16:49]"`. (`"tor"` is Thursday in my locale).

So this answer is not fully matching the question, since you don't have a way of providing the format string, but hopefully it will work out anyway. It should understand all formats that org-time-stamp handles.

```el
(defun jk-org-insert-time-stamp (time-string)
  (interactive "sTime: ")
  (let ((default-time (apply 'encode-time (decode-time))))
    (org-insert-time-stamp
     (apply 'encode-time (org-read-date-analyze time-string default-time default-time)) t t)))
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. The question was, `how can I parse a string with a specified format?`  This function inserts a timestring with a specified format.