# What's the inverse of (format-time-string "%s")?

Tags: time-date, parse-time

[Parsing formatted time string (inverse of format-time-string)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9974/2264) asks for a complete inverse of `format-time-string` with the ability to specify the source format, but I really just need to get from a UNIX time / epoch time to a real time value (like that which `(current-time)` returns.

In essence, I want the following:

```
(let* ((emacs-time (current-time))
       (unix-time  (string-to-number (format-time-string "%s" emacs-time))))
  (equal emacs-time (mystery-func unix-time)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In keeping with tradition, I was able to find the answer in Emacs itself while asking this question.

It turns out the standard time functions work with different kinds of values:

> Function arguments, e.g., the TIME argument to `current-time-string`,
>   accept a more-general "time value" format, which can be a list of
>   integers as above, or a single number for seconds since the epoch, or
>   `nil` for the current time.  You can convert a time value into a
>   human-readable string using `current-time-string` and
>   `format-time-string`, into a list of integers using `seconds-to-time`,
>   and into other forms using `decode-time` and `float-time`.  These
>   functions are described in the following sections.

So, `seconds-to-time` will do what's needed.  Note that since `(current-time)` returns microseconds as well – something not present in most UNIX timestamps – the assertion in the question won't hold as-written.  If you strip microseconds from `(current-time)`, though, they'll be the same :-)