# parse-time-string: doesn't accept ISO 8601 string contrary to what the documentation claim

Tags: time-date, parse-time

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html) suggests that `parse-time-string` can be fed ISO 8601 string, such as "1998-09-12T12:21:54-0200". However, `(parse-time-string "1998-09-12T12:21:54-0200")` returns `(nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)`.

> — Function: `parse-time-string string`
>
> This function parses the time-string string into a list of the following form:
>
> `(sec min hour day mon year dow dst tz)`
>
> The format of this list is the same as what decode-time accepts (see Time Conversion), and is described in more detail there. Any element that cannot be determined from the input will be set to nil. The argument string should resemble an RFC 822 (or later) or **ISO 8601 string**, like “Fri, 25 Mar 2016 16:24:56 +0100” or “**1998-09-12T12:21:54-0200**”, but this function will attempt to parse less well-formed time strings as well.

Related question: [Parsing formatted time string (inverse of format-time-string)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/parsing-formatted-time-string-inverse-of-format-time-string)

**EDIT**:

GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.8, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2020-01-13

Comment: That does seem like a bug! :-)

Comment: It is fixed in upstream emacs: it works fine in GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.13, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2020-04-23

Comment: @NickD: Please consider adding that to an existing answer or adding it as another answer. (Comments can be deleted at any time.)

Comment: @Drew: PTAL....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

This bug was reported as [bug 39001](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=39001) and fixed in [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=07a4dd8e6aa2787f809d12aa99b8914af91ae2b3) in upstream emacs. The patch to apply can be found [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?filename=0001-parse-time-string-now-parses-ISO-8601-format-strings.patch;att=1;msg=10;bug=39001).

Workaround:

The function `parse-iso8601-time-string` does parse ISO8601 string but eventually encode it with `encode-time`. The following snippet does what `parse-time-string` was supposed to do.

```
(decode-time 
    (parse-iso8601-time-string "1998-09-12T12:21:54-0200"))
```

returns

`(54 21 16 12 9 1998 6 t 7200)`

**Note**:

The value returned is partially wrong (the last three fields) because

```
(format-time-string "%Y" (decode-time 
    (parse-iso8601-time-string "1998-09-12T12:21:54-0200")))
```

is evaluated as `1970`.

**TODO**:

advice `parse-time-string` to check if its argument `string` matches `parse-time-iso8601-regexp`, if it does, apply the snippet above.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my adding the upstream emacs fix info to your answer. Let me know if you object.

Comment: It appears that `(format-time-string "%Y" (decode-time 
    (parse-iso8601-time-string "1998-09-12T12:21:54-0200")))` still evaluates to 1970. Emacs 28.1.